# Dangers of averaging between model approaches

Tags: modeling, prediction, forecast-combination

I am working with some ridership data that is broken down by route, year and month.  I have built and tested a whole bunch of models ranging from GLM, GEE, GENLIM, and Panel and ARIMA data models.  I believe some aspects of each of these model are correct when I predict on another dataset.  However, I am not sure that I agree with how fast some model approaches increase and the limit to which they increase to.

Is it a valid statistical approach to average say each of the best models estimations predictions together?  What sorts of issues would I be dealing with if I did?  Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 1):

The key word is "forecast combination". It's used a lot in Economic forecasting. As the term implies the averaging is not the only way, often not the best. Medians tend to be more stable. Other tricks would include removing the tails before combining. There's a ton of research on the subject, Google it. There's no simple answer to your question.

The main issue is that in case when all your models are crappy but one, you'll end up throwing out the forecast from that one model.

Comment: After doing some research online, I think this is what I am going for, but I want to make sure I am doing the analysis correctly.  Say for just a simple average, I would just average the predictions of the models without determining any weights.  However there are programs out there that can estimates possible weights based on the predictions of the various approaches?

Comment: I haven't seen weighted approaches used in practice. Where are you going to get weights from?

Comment: I found this package for R called EBMAforecast} http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/EBMAforecast/html/calibrateEnsemble.html.  It looks like it takes the actual and predicted values from both out of sample and in sample and then solves.